# Strange TCP Connections - How to kill

Tags: linux, macos, mac, virus, imap

My parents Mac is having some random issues - my mum paid £160 to get the computer repaired as there were some "trojans" according to the guy on the phone from india

On hearing this news I had a quick look, the firewall wasn't even turned on! This is now fixed.

I looked at the output of netstat -a and here is what I found

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp4       0      0  elaines-imac.hom.49206 imap19.mail.vip..imaps ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  elaines-imac.hom.49205 imap19.mail.vip..imaps ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  elaines-imac.hom.49202 115.115.67.53.st.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  elaines-imac.hom.49195 imap10.mail.vip..imaps ESTABLISHED
tcp4      88      0  elaines-imac.hom.49190 imap11.mail.vip..imaps CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  elaines-imac.hom.49187 17.172.233.91.5223     ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  elaines-imac.hom.49178 pop-secure.legac.pop3s CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  localhost.ipp          *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  localhost.ipp          *.*                    LISTEN     
udp4       0      0  *.*                    *.*                               
udp4       0      0  elaines-imac.hom.ntp   *.*                               
udp6       0      0  elaines-imac.loc.ntp   *.*
```

Some of these connections looks mighty suspicious, especially when one of them resolved to a Location in India.

Can anyone suggest what might be responsible for these and how i might go about terminating the erroneous ones.

Thanks for the time

Comment: They look like mail servers.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x

This will show you who is listening on the other end and it should help you decide on which files to delete and software to remove. Also check the firewall for any rules or programs that are allowed through that you are not familiar with.